# Restlet Https requests

Tags: java, restlet

I have successfully wrote `HTTP` request sending using **Restlet's** `ClientResource`:

```
public static String get(String url) {
  ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(url);
  Representation responseRepresentation = clientResource.get();
  String response = responseRepresentation.getText();
  return response;
}
```

Now I'm trying to write **`HTTPS`** requests `GET` and `POST` with **Restlet's** `ClientResource` but I'm not sure about the exact syntax.

Any reference and/or examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the code and be more specific about what you're not sure?

Comment: added the code, does it help?

Comment: The code you post it's a *GET* request is it working? For the post you could find an example [here](http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/SIMBAD/courses/doku.php?id=teaching_assistant:web_services:restful_post).

Comment: I have a POST code as well, I need HTTPS examples

Comment: The only point about **HTTPS** is to check if your server has a trusted certificate or not. If the server certificate is not trusted, you have to create a keystore for your client that include the server certificate as a trusted certificate.